# Hilbert's inequality for $\left|\sum_{n\neq m}\frac{a_n \bar{a}_m}{\left(n-m\right)^\lambda}\right|$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, reference-request

We know that, the Hilbert's inequality for double series states
$$\left|\sum_{n\neq m}\frac{a_n \bar{a}_m}{n-m}\right|\leq\pi \sum_n |a_n|^2$$
for $a_n\in\mathbb C$. I'd like to know if inequalities of this type on 
$$\left|\sum_{n\neq m}\frac{a_n \bar{a}_m}{\left(n-m\right)^\lambda}\right|$$
are known. Here $\lambda>1$.

Answers, suggestions, bibliographical material are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252371/hilberts-double-series-theorem-sum-n-m-fraca-n-b-mmn-and-its-generali?rq=1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261679/convergence-of-double-series-sum-n-m-in-mathbb-z-c-n-barc-m-frac-sinn?rq=1